# Can somebody explain to me this implementation of 3-way-quicksort

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I am a bit lost trying to understand this code, after the first while iteration the sort function is called again, several times, and the values passed to "sort" are changing:

```
sort(a, lo, lt - 1, c);
sort(a, gt + 1, hi, c);
```

I dont understand why, what does modifying those indexes mean and how does it impact the sorting.
I tried debugging this piece of code and it looks to me that those index changes are restricting the area to sort to either the right side of the array or the left one, where after the first iteration, most of the larger and smaller values should be.
Could anybody shed some light on it and clarify the purpose of those 2 lines of code?

```
public class Quick3Way{

    public static void sort(Comparable[] a)
    {
        StdRandom.shuffle(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    public static void sort(Object[] a, Comparator c)
    {
        StdRandom.shuffle(a);
        sort(a, 0, a.length - 1, c);
    }


    public static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if (hi <= lo) return;

        // partition
        int i = lo;
        int lt = lo;
        int gt = hi;

        while (i <= gt){
            if      (less(a[i], a[lt]))     exch(a, i++, lt++);

            else if (less(a[lt], a[i]))     exch(a, i, gt--);
            else                            i++;
        }

        sort(a, lo, lt - 1);
        sort(a, gt + 1, hi);
    }

    public static void sort(Object[] a, int lo, int hi, Comparator c)
    {
        if (hi <= lo) return;

        // partition
        int i = lo;
        int lt = lo;
        int gt = hi;

        while (i <= gt){
            if (less(a[i], a[lt], c))       exch(a, i++, lt++);
            else if (less(a[lt], a[i], c))  exch(a, i, gt--);
            else                            i++;
        }

        sort(a, lo, lt - 1, c);
        sort(a, gt + 1, hi, c);
    }


    // test client
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] arraypart = { 1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,710,30,0,50};
        Integer[] arraysort = new Integer[arraypart.length];
        System.arraycopy(arraypart, 0, arraysort, 0, arraypart.length);

        System.out.print("Original:\t");
        for (int str : arraypart)
            System.out.print(str);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Full sort:\t");
        Quick3Way.sort(arraysort);
        for (int str : arraysort)
            System.out.print(str);
        System.out.println();
    }

    // private
    private static void exch(Comparable[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        Comparable tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    private static void exch(Object[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        Object tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }


    private static boolean less(Comparable a, Comparable b)
    { return a.compareTo(b) < 0; }

    private static boolean less(Object a, Object b, Comparator c)
    { return c.compare(a, b) < 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm not convinced this code is 3-way quicksort, I think it's just regular quicksort although it would be nice if someone more experience could check the code and verify this. But as for those two lines hopefully the following will help:

so you have chose a pivot element. Let's call it x

you then make two partitions. So the list now contains everything less than x (not necessarily sorted) FOLLOWED BY x FOLLOWED BY everything greater than x (not necessarily sorted).

So you know for sure x is in the right place. Now you need to sort the parts at either side of x. That is where this code comes in:

```
sort(a, lo, lt - 1, c);
sort(a, gt + 1, hi, c);
```

roughly translated to:

sort(the_list, from_start, to_one_before_x, with_this_comparitor);

sort(the_list, from_one_after_x, to_end, with_this_comparitor);

Obviously as the algorithm recurses you can replace from_start with from_start_of_partition and from_end with from_end_of_parition etc.